# How to extract data from image that contains tabular data?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract, pillow,cv2 to OCR an image and get the text present in the image. Since my input is a scanned PDF document, I first converted it into an image (JPEG) format and then tried extracting the text. I am only half way there. The input is a table and the titles are not being displayed, since the titles have a black background. I also tried `getstructuringelement` but unable to figure out a way. Here is what I have done until now-

```
import cv2
import os  
import numpy as np 
import pytesseract
#import pillow 

#Since scanned PDF can't be handled by pdf2image, convert the scanned PDF into a JPEG format using the below code- 
filename = path   
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
pages = convert_from_path(filename, 500) for page in pages:
page.save("dest", 'JPEG')


imgname = "path" 
oriimg = cv2.imread(imgname,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
cv2.imshow("original image", oriimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)


#img = cv2.resize(oriimg,None,fx=0.5,fy=0.5,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) 
img = cv2.resize(oriimg,(700,1500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) 
#here length height  
cv2.imshow("lol", img) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.imwrite("changed_dimensionsimgpath", img)


import PIL.Image  
image = cv2.imread(imgname,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
grayedimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) grayedimg = 
cv2.threshold(grayedimg, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 
cv2.imwrite("H://newim.jpg", grayedimg)


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract- 
OCR\tesseract.exe"


text = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open("path"))
print(text)
```

My input table looks like below. The regions which have black background are not being identified by OCR and not being extracted as text.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image: My sample input]

Output of this code for the image sample-

```
Sun by Select .

F'I‘L‘Mlm":[ [Juir SHIIEF'. ”ﬁllﬁt Fadll'fi



Brand Type Fragranm Unit: Ithange Dollm 'LChanga Men
Eleanit' Sprayl Grange J.?IEBﬂI-Eﬂ' 11% '5H'1Elﬁ9ﬂﬂﬂ 35% I E
Eleanlt! kﬁmnsul' Grange IEEEESWI 39% I521LESM1MH 1113553 ‘ E
Dehuxe F‘mmr [emu 525.940 461% '51:EE?,GED,00 433.6% 5
Datum: Anus»! ﬁring?) 4,3341%} 29% 513573300119 215% E
Dem Spray ‘Drangr: £432,100 09% 515.223.:53000 154%

Min Blaster Aemgul: Dramge ”2114033111 59% :SHSiMMﬂ H94:

DiFlEIESIEf Sprawl Drama “NEW. 50% ‘5E1D1_E-BDM 141% I
Incredlme Spray Lem 1.513.410" 483% a HELENE] $11143 I E

t“ In

1'"
```

Comment: I cant really figure out what the question is

Comment: @MEdwin I am using pytesseract to extract text from an image. My image is actually a table that has data (shown in the question). I can't show what is in the table. but I used the above code and was able to extract text from tabular data (which is in green color) but the parts colored in red couldn't be extracted from the image. How do i proceed with this? I had ideas of changing the background color, but didn't seem to help (I might be wrong)

Comment: Okay, I get you now. So, since we cant see the images and what it extracted. Is it possible to create a test case (simplified) that can capture the issue. So we can actually see the full image, text extracted, text that cant be extracted. then we can see why the code isnt doing what you expect?

Comment: @MEdwin, Okay sure,I have done the changes now. please help

Comment: @developer where are the red and green colors you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: @Alderven, I changed the sample input. Please ignore the red green thing. Editing it right away

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change a part of the background color of an image, when the image is a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176311/is-it-possible-to-change-a-part-of-the-background-color-of-an-image-when-the-im)

Comment: @beaker, That question has also been posted by me. I didn't receive any help, so i reposted it.

Comment: @developer I understand, that's why I flagged this one as a duplicate. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) Nowhere in there does it suggest you resubmit the same question, especially after only 4 hours. You haven't given most people time to even see the question, much less answer.

Comment: @beaker Oh. Thanks. I didn't know about it. Will remember it the next time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955328/remove-all-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-from-an-image/53962592#53962592, which is an ImageMagick solution. You might be able to find similar commands in OpenCV. Otherwise, ImageMagick is built into Linux distributions and is available for Windows and Mac.

Comment: Converting to JPG is a bad idea. It is a lossy format and contain artifacts that might affect your results. You should use a non-lossy compressed image format, such as PNG or TIFF.

Comment: did you get any sol? I posted my ques-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172144/how-to-fetch-info-in-structure-formate-with-tesseract-ocr-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Using cv2 is good after cv2.imwrite(temp_filename, gray_img)

```
import PIL.Image  
Use config='-psm 6'
page_str = image_to_string(Image.open(temp_filename), lang="eng", config='-psm 6')
```

This  will return good data from table images