# How to fetch info in structure formate with tesseract ocr in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am using Ubuntu.

Here is my Image that i get from internet.

My concern is to get data as it is formated  in the Image

and dump it into the Text file (position has to be maintained (95-97% accuracy))

I am working with [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

[image]

[image: Image-2]

[almost same question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178962/how-to-extract-data-from-image-that-contains-tabular-data)

my code-:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/demo.jpg")

d1 = pytesseract.image_to_data(img)

print(d1)
```

It gives me completely a wrong output from what I am expecting

In short, I want to convert this Image(with alignment) to text file (or CSV file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use tesseract output in HOCR to retain positional information. Converting these kinds of documents directly into text retaining positional information is a very tricky and hard problem. I can give you an intermediate solution that can give you a data frame with each word and its coordinates so that you can parse it to extract key-value information using the coordinates.

```
### this will save the tesseract output as "demo.hocr" 
pytesseract.pytesseract.run_tesseract(
            "demo.jpg", "demo",
            extension='.html', lang='eng', config="hocr")
```

HOCR is an HTML like representation that contains a lot of metadata like line information, word information, its coordinates, etc present.
For better handling, I have a parser that will directly parse it and give you a data frame with words and its coordinates.
I have created a package in pip called [tesseract2dict](https://github.com/Sreekiranar/tesseract2dict) for this.
You can easily install it using `pip install tesseract2dict`
This is how you can use that.

```
import cv2
from tesseract2dict import TessToDict
td=TessToDict()
inputImage=cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg')
### function 1
### this is for getting word level information as a dataframe
word_dict=td.tess2dict(inputImage,'outputName','outfolder')

### function 2
### this is for getting plain text for a given coordinates as (x,y,w,h)
text_plain=td.word2text(word_dict,(0,0,inputImage.shape[1],inputImage.shape[0]))
```

PS: This package is only compatible with Tesseract 5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage pytesseract parameters to achieve what you're looking for.
More specifically that `Output` class you imported holds all the supported output types by pytesseract

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/demo.jpg")

# my favorite type is Output.DICT but since you mentioned CSV
d1 = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DATAFRAME)

print(type(d1))
d1.to_csv('ocr_dump.csv')
```